# writing joins in mulitple ways in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I noticed the same join can be written in two different ways as mentioned below. I don't see any change in the result.

Is this different format just for readability?

Pattern-1:

```
select * from 
(
  Table-1 A
  LEFT JOIN Table-2 B ON ((A.id = A .id))
);
```

Pattern-2:

```
select * from 
Table-1 a
LEFT JOIN Table-2 B on B.id = A.ID
```

Comment: SQL is a high level language. I good way to check how the database processed your query on this type of stuff is to do an explain on the statements and see how the optimizer goes after the data.

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are equal.

The SQL parser internally would regard the braces as present, because they implicitly are.
But without braces it's much easier to read (at least for these short statements)